# how to listen for new tweets for an @mention using tweepy?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I am new to tweepy. And tried to implement an api which can listen the new tweets for a @mention or screen name.

```
tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=username)
```

But it is not listening the new tweets. Could you please help me to understand how it can be implemented so that whenever a tweet comes with '@mention'. the api should listen immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def on_data( self, status ):
    print("Entered on_data()")
    print(status.text, flush = True)
    return True
...
user = api.verify_credentials()
# this is just for getting user. without this also connection can be established
if user:
    print(user.id)
    print('started')
twitter_stream=Stream(auth,StdOutListener())
print('Stream created...')
twitter_stream.filter(follow=[user.id_str], is_async=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Creating a StreamListener

The on_data method of Tweepy’s StreamListener conveniently passes data from statuses to the on_status method. 
Create class MyStreamListener inheriting from StreamListener and overriding on_status.

```
import tweepy
```

## override tweepy.StreamListener to add logic to on_status

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)
```

## Creating a Stream

Need an API to stream with the right credentials for authentications. Once we have an API and a status listener we can create our stream object.

```
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
```

## start stream

```
myStream.filter(track=['python'])

myStream.filter(follow=["2211149702"])
```

## Async stream

```
myStream.filter(track=['python'], is_async=True)
```

## handling errors

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            #returning False in on_error disconnects the stream
            return False

        # returning non-False reconnects the stream, with backoff.
```

Comment: track =['python'] will collect all the tweets which matches the 'python'. But i need all tweets which contain @mention.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, get their twitter user id using [this](http://gettwitterid.com/).
Then, use this:

```
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import StreamListener

listener = StreamListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(config.ACCESS_TOKEN, config.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
stream = Stream(auth, listener)
stream.filter(follow=['1102105048253849600']) # user ID for random account
```

Comment: 'follow=id' will retrieve the all activities to the user id. my objective is to find the real time tweets. is there any way to make one more check to filter the tweet as part of api

Comment: In the answer above, when you are overriding the on_status function, do the following:
```python
uname = tweet.user.screen_name
uname = '@'+uname
if uname in tweet.text:
    print("User is mentioned in this tweet when searched with given hashtag")
```

a simple string matching. this will print that message if the user is mentioned in the tweet.

Comment: Thanks but without this check also we can collect tweets from the status object